# c# if else then statement with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, inferred-type

I have the following code:

```
if (intval == 0)
{
    var result = (from dm in datacontext.Trk
                  where dm.ID == 0
                  select dm);
}
else
{
   var result = (from dm in datacontext.Trk
                 where dm.ID != 0
                 select dm);
}

if (result != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

There is a swigly line under the result in `if (result!= null)`  saying that the name result does not exist in the current context.

Not sure how to fix this. I tried to initially `var result = null` but C# didn't like that.

Comment: A variable declared in a block `{ }` is limited to this block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
    var result = 
        intval == 0 
            ?(from dm in datacontext.Trk where dm.ID = 0 select dm) 
            :(from dm in datacontext.Trk where dm.ID != 0 select dm);

    if(results.Any())
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

The variable is limited to the block it is declared in. So you have two `result`s, one in `if` block and one in `else` block which are different and are not visible outside their blocks.

You need to define the variable out of blocks, but then you need to be specific about the type, because C# compiler needs direct assignment expression to infer the type for `var` keyword.

However, I suggest rethinking your code and doing somthing like following:

```
var result = from dm in datacontext.Trk
             where ((intval == 0) ? dm.ID == 0 : dm.ID != 0)
             select dm;

if (result.Any())
{
   // do something
}
```

Please also note that `result` will never be `null`, therefore, I have replaced it with `Any` but it is not a gist of the question, I believe.

Comment: this is excellent and should be shared all over the web, only good answer for any conditional where statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `result` before the if statement:

```
object result = null;

if (intval = 0)
{
   result = (from dm in datacontext.Trk
                 where dm.ID = 0
                 select dm);

}
else
{
   result = (from dm in datacontext.Trk
                 where dm.ID != 0
                 select dm);


 }

 if (result != null)
 {

  // do something

 }
```

Or you can keep the var declaration in this other variant:

```
var result = (from dm in datacontext.Trk
                 where dm.ID != 0
                 select dm);

if (intval = 0)
{
   result = (from dm in datacontext.Trk
                 where dm.ID = 0
                 select dm);

}

if (result != null)
{
   // do something

}
```

Now you should somehow find a way to either change that `if` or remove it completely because `result` cannot be `null` at that point.

Comment: Isn't the result of a LINQ query an IEnumerable<>? not an object?

Comment: @hanzolo: Yes it's true, but I decided to be neutral in this case, for the sake of generality, since he was using var.

Comment: @hanzolo any IEnumerable is also an object.

Comment: To tell the truth, initially I wanted to propose him a solution in which we first assign the result of the else, and if the condition is true we ovewrite it with the result of the else. That would have allowed him to keep the var declaration, but would not have been good performance-wise.

Comment: @L.B: His question was clearly about why the code does not compile. If he has other problems with the logic of his code he should create a separate question.

Comment: @Tudor, I can't understand the performance problem. `result = (from dm in datacontext.Trk
                 where dm.ID =!= 0
                 select dm);
` I thought  this is really executed when an iteration is done over it.

Comment: Yes but in case the if is true you execute both queries.

Comment: Ahm, yes, I see your point now. I misunderstood your comment. I guess I can add this idea to the answer then.

Comment: @hanzolo while it is true that any IEnumerable is also an object, it's a fairly useless fact.  You can assign the IEnumerable to an object reference, but once it's there, you can't do much of value with it; you can't enumerate it or call any linq methods on it without casting it back to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the where separately from the main query:

```
var result = from dm in datacontext.Trk select dm;
if (intval == 0)
{
    result = result.Where(dm => dm.ID == 0);
}
else
{
    result = result.Where(dm => dm.ID != 0);
}

if (result.Any())
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the result variable before the first if-else.

Also you need paranthesis around the condition in the second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This code would also cause the problem:

```
if (value == 0)
{
     int result = 1;
}
else
{
     string result = "testing";
}

if (result != 1)
{
     // do something
}
```

The first time result is an `int`, the second time I declare a `string`, and the third time `result` is undeclared. The reason that they can have different types is because the first two declarations belong to different scopes. Each `{ ... }` gets its own scope.

If you want to share one variable between scopes, you'll need to declare it outside. But now, since the same variable is used in all three places, there is a compiler error that the types don't match:

```
int result;

if (value == 0)
{
    result = 1;
}
else
{
    result = "testing"; // type error here
}

if (result != 1)
{
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TypeOfDm> dmList; // <=== Declare dmList outside of block statements.
if (intval == 0) { // <=== Use "==" for comparision, "=" is assignement.
    dmList = datacontext.Trk
        .Where(dm =>  dm.ID == 0)
        .ToList();
} else { 
    dmList = datacontext.Trk
        .Where(dm =>  dm.ID != 0)
        .ToList();
} 
if (dmList.Count != 0) { 
  // do something 
}
```

Note, with your code your result will always be non-null.